# Binding to a property via a ContentControl, using a DataTemplate and DataTemplateSelector

Tags: wpf, data-binding, contentcontrol

this is my xaml

```
    <Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
xmlns:basic="clr-namespace:Emule.GUI.Design.Templates" 
xmlns:Search="clr-namespace:Emule.GUI.Features.Search" 
xmlns:Finder="clr-namespace:Emule.GUI.Util.Finder"mc:Ignorable="d"
x:Class="Emule.GUI.Features.Search.View" Title="View" Height="454" Width="696">
```

```
 <!-- Default DataTemplate --> 
<DataTemplate x:Key="DefaultDataTemplate"> 
   <TextBox Grid.Row="2"  Grid.Column="2" x:Name="joe"
          Visibility="{Binding OperatorValueVisibility, Mode=OneWay}"
          Text="{Binding OperatorValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" /> 
</DataTemplate>

<!-- DataTemplate for string list --> 
<DataTemplate x:Key="ListStringDataTemplate"> 
  <basic:ListValuesSearch MinHeight ="740" x:Name="ListValues" /> 
</DataTemplate> 

<!-- DataTemplate Selector -->

<Search:PropertyDataTemplateSelector  x:Key="templateSelector" 
    DefaultDataTemplate="{StaticResource DefaultDataTemplate}" 
    BooleanDataTemplate="{StaticResource BooleanDataTemplate}" 
    EnumDataTemplate="{StaticResource EnumDataTemplate}"/>
```

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
    <ContentControl ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource templateSelector}" 
                    Content="{Binding Path=PoDFinder.CodicePod}" />
</StackPanel> 

</Window>
```

and this is my control (wpftoolkit data grid)

```
<UserControl x:Class="Emule.GUI.Design.Templates.ListValuesSearch" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    xmlns:WpfToolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"

xmlns:Finder="clr-namespace:Emule.GUI.Util.Finder">

<UserControl.Resources> 
   <ResourceDictionary> 
     <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries> 
       <ResourceDictionary Source="DataGrid.Generic.xaml"/> 
     </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries> 
   </ResourceDictionary> 
</UserControl.Resources> 

<StackPanel> 
    <WpfToolkit:DataGrid ItemsSource= "{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContentControl}, 
    Path=OperatorValues, Mode=TwoWay}" x:Name="ListValuesSearchControl"> 

     <WpfToolkit:DataGrid.Columns > 
        <WpfToolkit:DataGridTextColumn Header="Lista valori" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Path=Item}"/> 
    </WpfToolkit:DataGrid.Columns> 
   </WpfToolkit:DataGrid> 
</StackPanel> 

</UserControl>
```

my data template `ListStringDataTemplate` don't show the data datagrid (show the type name) but note that if I use the control `<basic:ListValuesSearch MinHeight ="740"  x:Name="ListValues" />` directly without data template selector work fine.

I think the problem is this path `ItemsSource= "{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContentControl}, Path=OperatorValues, Mode=TwoWay}"`

I can solve this, wath I wrong?

thanks

t.

Answer (score 0):

why not get rid of the DataTemplateSelector and specify the the DataType in your DataTemplates? its much easier and almost work.

in your usercontrol your binding should look like this but just if PoDFinder.CodicePod is your collection. if not you have to add the path to the property.

```
<StackPanel> 
 <WpfToolkit:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}"> 
   <WpfToolkit:DataGrid.Columns> 
    <WpfToolkit:DataGridTextColumn Header="Lista valori" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Path=Item}"/> 
   </WpfToolkit:DataGrid.Columns> 
  </WpfToolkit:DataGrid> 
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: this is the error... the ListStringDataTemplate="{StaticResource ListStringDataTemplate}" is not in the PropertyDataTemplateSelector with this correction work fine

Comment: like i said there is no need of datatemplateselector, your code will become much cleaner with just datatemplate, viewmodels und right binding :)